# Displaying list of logged in users in Front side using Joomla 2.5 component

Tags: joomla, jprofiler, loginview

I would like to display all login user list in Front side  using Joomla 2.5  component.

Can any body tell me how do do this?

I would also want to develop change password and news subscription module.

Comment: i want ans as soon as possible

Comment: Please do some research first!!! So many people have been asking questions the last few days demanding things without trying anything of their own and thus not receiving answers or very short answers. We will help you if you put effort into what you're trying to do yourself.

Comment: hey..i research  lots of but i dont found anything regard to this...so i want help from you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$db =JFactory::getDBO();

$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('*')
->from('#__users');
$db->setQuery($query);

$rows = $db->loadObjectList();
foreach ($rows as $row) {      
    $user = JFactory::getUser($row->id);
    $status = $user->guest;
    if(!$status){
        echo $row->name.'---Email'.$row->email;
    }
}
```

Use this [extension](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/custom-code-in-modules/15251) to implement its in your site if you need quick solution.

Hope it helps..

Comment: You should use Joomla 2.5 coding standards for your query

Comment: besides, you don't need to use a query to get the user information. This is done using `$user = JFactory::getUser();`

Comment: @Lodder but he needs all logged in users

Comment: yup, sorry, had a mind blank and forgot that getUser gets the current user.

Comment: @JobinJose Thank for your replay but i download this extenstion  and try to write my php customize code in that but its not working.

Comment: @user2823265 I didn't used that plugin before but i trust the code it will works try it in any component view

Comment: this code display all users list... i want only thos who are login in site currently

Comment: @user2823265 - It should display all logged in users as you asked. In the code you will see `$status = $user->guest` the the if statement detects the opposite. To use the code, try using an extension like [DirectPHP](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/custom-code-in-content/4470)

Comment: is it producing an error? Is it displaying something else? or is not not displaying anything at all?

Comment: @Lodder its display all user from site.. but i want to display those user who currently login in site